# System-wide hotkey for an application

Tags: cocoa, macos, button

I have a simple window with 3 buttons and I am trying to add a system-wide hot key so i can "press" those buttons without having to switch to that app, press a button and then go back to what I was doing.

Something like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> press button 1, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> press button 2, etc.

Is there any way to achieve this in Cocoa (with Objective-C)?
Thanks, code is appreciated since I am a total newbie on Cocoa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also didn't like PTHotKey, so I ended up writing a new wrapper, available here:

http://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey

**edit**

The 2 files you'd need are:

- [DDHotKeyCenter.h](http://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey/raw/master/DDHotKeyCenter.h)
- [DDHotKeyCenter.m](http://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey/raw/master/DDHotKeyCenter.m)

And you'd use it something like this:

```
- (IBAction) registerHotkey:(id)sender {
  DDHotKeyCenter * c = [[DDHotKeyCenter alloc] init];
  if (![c registerHotKeyWithKeyCode:kVK_ANSI_1 modifierFlags:(NSCommandKeyMask | NSShiftKeyMask) target:self action:@selector(hotkeyWithEvent:) object:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"unable to register hotkey");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"registered hotkey");
  }
  [c release];
}

- (void) hotkeyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)hkEvent {
  NSLog(@"Hotkey event: %@", hkEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay. It's been a busy week. This looks promising. Any way not to use the carbon framework?

Comment: @Jessica yes, but not really.  Yes if you're using 10.6 and you want to filter *every single key event* on the system looking for specific combinations to recognize.  No if you want true hotkey behavior.  I wouldn't worry about the Carbonness, though. This portion of Carbon was upgraded to be 64-bit compatible.

Comment: OK, let me try it. Two things: 1) do you have a direct link to a zip file (i don't use git and I can't find a download link on the page you posted). While the `how to use` is clear, I am a complete newbie. Do you have a small snippet that I can use as a guide for, let say, a hotkey cmd-shift-1?

Comment: Jessica: Use the “Download Source” button on that page.

Comment: @Jessica glad to hear it.  If you have any suggestions for how to improve the code, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

PTHotKey is old and busted (generates reams of warnings) on modern SDKs. Use [SGHotKeysLib](https://github.com/mattstevens/SGHotKeysLib) instead.

Both SGHotKeysLib and PTHotKey are reusable source code. You need only add the classes to your own project, then use them from your own classes.

Comment: great, thanks for the tip. Any chance you can post a little snippet? as I said, i'm only beginning with Cocoa

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called PTHotKey that makes this fairly easy. You can google PTHotKey or just grab it from http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/source/browse/trunk/Demo/HotKey/?r=2

Comment: thank you sbooth. question tho, when you say a library is it something I need to compile separatelly and then add to my app?