# Assign a hotkey to NSWindow in Xcode/Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an application with an NSMenuItem that launches a separate window and I was wondering if it would also be possible to add a hot-key combination so that it would be possible to also invoke the NSWindow via that as well.

I was thinking that it's not possible, because wouldn't the application have to be 'Active' for a hot-key to work?

So, where should I be looking? Because, honestly, I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: Try this [Global Hotkeys](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/)

Your hot-key will only work when the app is active.

Click where the square is and press the combo of keys that you want to assign:

[image]

In case you mess up the combo of keys, you can clear it here *(the "Clear" button at the bottom)*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking.  In that case, is there any way to provide the functionality I was looking for?

Comment: Pressing the key combo will activate the menu, which will in turn open your NSWindow ;-)

Comment: Now, is there anyway to keep my app persistently 'active' so that I can use the key combo while another app is active? Say, while I'm typing in Pages, I can control-shift-T to activate my app?

Comment: Updated my answer with a nice post on Glopbal hotkeys.

Comment: There are Cocoa wrappers to make global hotkeys easier to set up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3760318/30461